# web2py site is not loading the usual css, just plain ugly html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web2py, lighttpd

I'm moving my web2py powered site from one server to another. After fighting a permissions problem with `/tmp/fcgi.sock` default file location for weeks I finally understood that is was better put it under `/srv/http/` on Arch Linux on any other place owned by the user who runs the http server (in my case `http`) as indicated [here](https://community.webfaction.com/questions/6336/lighttpd-to-decrease-memory-usage). Now I'm trying to figure out what is happening with the look and feel of the site because web2py is loading plain ugly html instead of the usual bootstrap twitter theme. I remember having this problem before, and solved it with the proper permissions, but I have tested several permissions on the web2py's folder and all of them give me the same ugly results. Any pointer to a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here was the problem: My combination was lighttpd + web2py on Arch Linux, and lighhtpd have not the proper mimetype assignation for css, so the server was treating css files as ocstream. The solution is to add `".css" => "text/css"` to the mime type section of the `lighttpd.conf` for example:

```
mimetype.assign = (
    ".html" => "text/html",
    ".txt" => "text/plain",
    ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
    ".png" => "image/png",
    ".css" => "text/css",
    "" => "application/octet-stream"
)
```

For details see on: [Styles (CSS) not working properly](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lighttpd#Styles_.28CSS.29_not_working_properly) on the Arch Wiki.

Thanks to [@neoecos](https://twitter.com/neoecos) for helping with this on twitter.